# How do you find nth maclaurin/taylor series or polynomial?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Like for example, one of my homework problems is
g(x)= x<sup>2</sup>e<sup>x<sup>3</sup></sup>

and it's asking me to find g<sup>(40)</sup>(0)
am I supposed to find the derivative 40 times and plug 0 in for x?

I turned the function into a maclaurin series in sigma notation
and not sure what to do

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ $\frac{x^{3n+2}}{n!}$

Comment: Hint: how do the coefficients of your series relate to the derivative?

Comment: The coefficients in a MacLaurin series are the derivatives of the function at $0$, so you could use these

Comment: You are supposed to look at that series $\sum x^{3n+2}/n!$ and compare with the standard Maclaurin series $\sum g^{(k)}(0)x^k/k!$.

Answer (score 1):

We can form a series that is somewhat easier to work with by noting that $ \ \frac{d}{dx} \ [e^{x^3}] \ = \ 3x^2 · e^{x^3} \ \ , $ so that we produce the anti-derivative series
$$ G(x) \ \ = \ \  \frac13 \  e^{x^3} \ \ =  \ \frac13 \ \sum_{n \ = \ 0}^{\infty} \ \frac{1}{n!} \ (x^3)^n \ \ = \ \ \frac13 \ \sum_{n \ = \ 0}^{\infty} \ \frac{x^{3n}}{n!} \ \ ,    $$

with $ \ G'(x) \ = \ g(x) \ = \ x^2 e^{x^3} \ . $  The series for $ \ G(x) \ $ is non-zero *only* for every third term, that is to say,

$$ G^{(n)}(0) \ \ = \ \ \left\{  \begin{array}{rcl} a_{n} \ \ ,  & \ \text{for} \ n = 3k \ \ , \ \ k \ \ \text{a non-negative integer}   \\ 0 \ \ , & \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right. \ \ . $$

Since $ \ g^{(40)}(0) \ = \ G^{(41)}(0) \ \ , $ and $ \ 41 \ $ is not a multiple of $ \ 3 \ \ , $ we can simply conclude that $ \ g^{(40)}(0) \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  (Had the problem asked for $ \ g^{(41)}(0) \ \ \text{or} \ \ g^{(50)}(0) \ \   $ (as appears in one of the answers -- the original version of the post?), we would have more work to do, as discussed below.

$$ \ \ $$

Another way we can approach the problem is to make use of the "higher-derivatives" version of the Product Rule,
$$ \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \ [f_1(x) · f_2(x)] \ \ = \ \ \sum_{k \ = \ 0}^{n} \ \binom{n}{k} \ f_1^{(k)}(x) · f_2^{(n-k)}(x) \ \ , $$

which behaves like a binomial expansion.  This will be of help to us if we define, as we did above, $ \ G(x) \ = \ \frac{1}{3} · e^{x^3} \ = \ \frac{1}{3} · e^u \ = \ y \ \ , $ so that $ \ g(x) \ = \ G'(x) \ = \ u' · y \ \ . $  We will then set  $ \ f_1 = u' \ $ and $ \ f_2 = y \ \   $  in making our calculations.

This may look daunting for the derivative we wish to determine, but there are features of the function that lead to considerable simplification.  We have $ \ G(0) = \frac13 \ $ and $ \ u = x^3 \ \Rightarrow \ u' = 3x^2 \ , \ u'' = 6x \ , \ u''' = 6 \ \ , $ and $ \ u^{(k)} = 0 \ $ for $ \ k \ge 4 \ \ . $  What this tells us is that the number of terms in the expansion for successive derivatives is quite limited.  Moreover, since we are evaluating the derivatives of $ \ g(x) \ $ at $ \ x = 0 \ $ , the only non-zero value for the $ \ u^{(n)}  $ 's is $ \ u''' = 6 \ \ . $

With this in mind, we see that

$  g(0) \ = \ G'(0) \ = \ y'(0) \ = \ 0 · \frac13 \ = \ 0 \ \ , $

$  g'(x) \ = \ G''(x) \ = \ y'' \ =  \ u''· y \ + \ u'· y' \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ g'(0) \ = \ 0 · \frac13 \ + \ 0 · 0 \ = \ 0 \ \ , $

$  g''(x) \  = \ y''' \ =  \ u'''· y \ + \ 2 · u''· y' \ + \ u'·y'' \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ g''(0) \ = \ 6 · \frac13 \ + \ 2 · 0 · 0 \ + \ 0·0 \ = \ 2 \ \ . $

Here, we attain our first non-zero derivative with $ \ G'''(0) \ = \ g''(0) \ \ . $  With the next derivative, our expressions begin to include derivatives of $ \ u \ $ which are simply zero.

$  g'''(x) \  = \ y^{(4)} \ =  \ u^{(4)}· y \ + \ 3 · u'''· y' \ + \ 3·u''·y'' \ + \ u'·y''' $
$ \Rightarrow \ \ g'''(0) \ = \ 0 · \frac13 \ + \ 3 · \frac13 · 0 \ + \ 3·0·0 \ + \ 0·6 \ = \ 0 \ \ , $

$  g^{(4)}(x) \  = \ y^{(5)} \ =  \ u^{(5)}· y \ + \ 4 · u^{(4)}· y' \ + \ 6·u'''·y'' \ + \ 4·u''·y''' \ + \ u'·y^{(4)} $
$ \Rightarrow \ \ g^{(4)}(0) \ = \ 0 \ + \ 0 \ + \ 6  ·  \frac13  ·  0 \ + \ 4·0·2 \ + \ 0 \ = \ 0 \ \ , $

and

$  g^{(5)}(x) \  = \ y^{(6)} \ =  \ u^{(6)}· y \ + \ 5 · u^{(5)}· y' \ + \ 10·u^{(4)}·y'' \ + \ 10·u'''·y''' \ + \ 5·u''·y^{(4)} \ + \ u'·y^{(5)} $
$ \Rightarrow \ \ g^{(5)}(0) \ = \ 0 \ + \ 0 \ + \ 0 \ + \ 10·6·2 \ + \ 0 \ + \ 0  \ = \ \binom{5}{3}·6·2 \ = \   120 \ \ . $

What becomes clear from this examples is that the non-zero derivatives for non-negative integer $ \ k \ $ are given by the recursion relation

$$ g^{(3k + 2)}(0) \  = \ y^{(3k + 3)}(0) \ =  \ \binom{3k+2}{3k}·u'''·y^{(3k)}(0)  \ =  \ \binom{3k+2}{3k}·6·y^{(3k)}(0) \ \ , \ \ y(0) \ = \ \frac13 \ \ . $$

Hence,

$$ g^{(8)}(0) \  = \ y^{(9)}(0) \ =  \  \binom{8}{6}·6·y^{(6)}(0) \ = \ \binom{8}{6}·6· \left[\binom{5}{3}·6·2 \right] \ = \ 20,160 \ \ ,  $$
$$ g^{(11)}(0) \  = \ y^{(12)}(0) \ =  \  \binom{11}{9}·6·y^{(9)}(0) \ = \ 55·6·20,160 \ = \ 6,652,800 \ \ ,  $$

and so forth.  We observe that while $ \ g^{(41)}(0) \  = \ y^{(42)}(0) \ $ would be *enormous*, $ \ g^{(40)}(0) \  = \ y^{(41)}(0) \ $ is not in this set of derivatives, and so is equal to zero.

$$ \ \ $$

We might like to have something a bit simpler to work with than the recursion relation for the non-zero derivatives.  If we write out the last example in full, we obtain

$$ g^{(11)}(0) \ \  = \ \ \binom{11}{9}·6·\binom{8}{6}·6·  \binom{5}{3}·6·\binom{2}{0}·6·\frac13 $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{11·10·9·8·7·6·5·4·3·2·1}{2 \ · \ 9 \ · \ 2 \ · \ 6 \ · \ 2 \ · \ 3 \ · \ 2} \ · \ 6^3 \ · \ 2  \ \ = \ \ \frac{11!}{2^3 \  · \ 3^3 \ · \ (3·2·1) \ · \ 2} \ · \ 6^3 \ · \ 2 \ \ = \ \ \frac{11!}{3!} \ \ . $$

The general calculation yields $ g^{(3k + 2)}(0) \  = \ \frac{(3k+2)!}{k!} \ \ , $ for integer $ \ k \ge 0 \ $ ; this completes the derivation characterization  given above

$$ G^{(n+3)}(0) \ \ = \ \ \left\{  \begin{array}{rcl} \frac{(3k+2)!}{k!} \ \ ,  & \ \text{for} \ n = 3k \ \ , \ \ k \ \ \text{a non-negative integer}   \\ 0 \ \ , & \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right. \ \ . $$

Inserting this into the general term for a Maclaurin series, we then produce

$$  g(x) \ \ = \ \ x^2 · e^{x^3} \ \ = \ \ \sum_{m \ = \ 0}^{\infty} \ \frac{g^{(m)}(0) }{m!} \ x^m    $$
[removing the "zero terms"]
$$ = \ \ \sum_{k \ = \ 0}^{\infty} \ \frac{(3k+2)! \ / \ k! }{(3k+2)!} \ x^{3k+2} \ \ = \ \  \sum_{k \ = \ 0}^{\infty} \ \frac{x^{3k+2} }{k!} \ \ = \ \ x^2 \ + \ x^5 \ + \ \frac12 · x^8 \ + \ \frac16 · x^{11} \ + \ \ldots \ \ ,   $$

in agreement with the method of substitution into the series for $ \ e^u \ $ and **Gary's** comment.

Answer (score -2):

Since
$$g(x) = x^2 e^{x^3} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{3n+2}}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{(2n+2)}\frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty g^{(n)}(0)\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
So that $$g^{(n)}(0) = x^{(2n+2)}$$
Therefore (for $n = 50$) $$g^{(50)}(0) = x^{102}$$

Comment: The value of the derivative is a number, it cannot depend on $x$. To obtain the correct answer, note that the series may be written $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(3n + 2)!}}{{n!}}\frac{{x^{3n + 2} }}{{(3n + 2)!}}} .
$$ Thus, $$
g^{(50)} (0) = g^{(3 \cdot 16 + 2)} (0) = \frac{{(3 \cdot 16 + 2)!}}{{16!}} = \frac{{50!}}{{16!}}.
$$ Note that the $n$th derivative at $0$ is $0$ if $n$ is not $2 \mod 3$. Hence, $g^{(40)}(0)=0$.